# How to make React JS & Tailwind Carousel?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, tailwind-css

iam just learning about React JS and a Tailwind, so i want to make a Carousel for my website project using a React JS & TailwindCSS, I've already make the Carousel but its not done yet, i want to make the Carousel Slide Horizontally and if the Carousel reach the end i iwant to make it back to beginning. Here's my code

`

```
<div className="mx-10 py-5 overflow-x-hidden">
      <div className={`flex flex-none min-w-screen bg-gray-900 space-x-10 transition-transform duration-300 -translate-x-[${index}rem]`}>
        <div className={`wrapper flex-none w-[55%] h-48 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-300 to-cyan-400 rounded-3xl text-3xl`}>

        </div>
        <div className={`flex-none w-[55%] h-48 bg-gradient-to-r from-fuchsia-600 to-pink-500 rounded-3xl`}>

        </div>
        <div className={`flex-none w-[55%] h-48 bg-gradient-to-r from-red-400 to-orange-300 rounded-3xl`}>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`
Sorry for my english

I want to make my Carousel works, the Carousel that i make can slide from begin to end, and at the end it will back to beginning again.

Comment: You wanna see the first card after the last one or you want it to scroll back to the beginning when you reach the end? The first option would be called an "infinite" carrousel. I'm sure you can search for it.